# Issue with including a html file with relative urls

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, directory

I have a file from a third-party script where all the URLs are like

```
<img src="images/main.png" />
<a href="css/one/two.css" />
```

Etc for all the Javascript, CSS includes, links and images. When you place all the files in the root directory, it works fine.

But I am using CodeIgniter, and need to include this script which is just one html file. But when I include it say from a URL/controller like:

```
http://www.example.com/home/custom/
```

All the URLs mess up inside the third party script because it's now expecting to find all the content inside /home/custom/images/main.css etc.

What's the best way to go about this? I don't want to modify the third party script to update all the URLs to point to the correct directory unless it's the last resort.

Directory Structure:

```
application
  views
    page
      third party script here
uploads
system
index.php
```

So when the script is placed inside application/views/page/ the URLs end up looking like http://www.example.com/page/images/main.png

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's a third-party script that you normally just drop in to get working. I don't want to modify every single link to include the base_url() code if I can help it.

Comment: You can change directory at the top of your file [`chdir();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)

Comment: Please explain your files and directories structure.

Comment: if all of them doesn't include `base_url();` why not replace `src="` and `href="` with `src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>` and `href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>` respectively?

Comment: Hi, because the script also uses some really complicated javascript files which seems to be loading URLs that are relative too.

Comment: I've added the directory structure to try and give a bit more information.